# Include `bourbon` from SCSS file (webpack)

Tags: node.js, webpack, import, sass, bourbon

I'm trying to get **bourbon** (package for SCSS mixins etc.), **node-sass** and **webpack** to work in harmony.

After running the webpack build command I get the following error:

```sh
ERROR in ./src/sass/style.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: no mixin named transform
        on line 12 of /home/navix/code/unsub-page/src/sass/style.scss
>>   @include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
```

Notice webpack is not complaining about the `@import`, though. Looking at the build folder, the compiled CSS indeed only comprises the normalize.css code.

## Setup

I have the following **packages** installed:

- bourbon
- node-sass
- css-loader
- style-loader
- sass-loader
- webpack
- webpack-cli
- webpack-dev-server
- postcss-loader
- autoprefixer
- html-webpack-plugin
- mini-css-extract-plugin

My entry JS file just imports `normalize.css` and my custom `style.scss`. The SCSS file just contains a simple setup to test bourbon:

```css
@import 'bourbon';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300');

body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #1d77ef;
}

.select-ctr {
  @include position(absolute, 50% x x 50%);
  @include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
}
```

This is my CSS pipeline:

```js
test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
use: [
  {
    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
  },
  {
    loader: 'css-loader'
  },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')()]
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
      sassOptions: {
        indentWidth: 4,
        includePaths: [require('bourbon').includePaths]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Bourbon [removed a number of prefixing features](https://www.bourbon.io/docs/migrating-from-v4-to-v5/) in v5, including the `transform` mixin.

With a bit of luck, you should be able to get it working by replacing any instance of this in your code:

```
@include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
```

…with this:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```